# Save non-SparkDataFrame from Azure Databricks to local computer as .RData

Tags: r, databricks, azure-databricks, sparkr

In Databricks (`SparkR`), I run the batch algorithm of the self-organizing map in parallel from the `kohonen` package as it gives me considerable reductions in computation time as opposed to my local machine. However, after fitting the model I would like to download/export the trained model (a `list`) to my local machine to continue working with the results (create plots etc.) in a way that is not available in Databricks. I know how to save & download a `SparkDataFrame` to csv:

```
sdftest # a SparkDataFrame
write.df(sdftest, path = "dbfs:/FileStore/test.csv", source = "csv", mode = "overwrite")
```

However, I am not sure how to do this for a 'regular' R `list` object.

Is there any way to save the output created in Databricks to my local machine in `.RData` format? If not, is there a workaround that would still allow me to continue working with the model results locally?

**EDIT :**

```
library(kohonen)

# Load data
sdf.cluster <- read.df("abfss://cluster.csv", source = "csv", header="true", inferSchema = "true")

# Collet SDF to RDF as kohonen::som is not available for SparkDataFrames
rdf.cluster <- SparkR::collect(sdf.cluster)

# Change rdf to matrix as is required by kohonen::som
rdf.som <- as.matrix(rdf.cluster)
  
# Parallel Batch SOM from Kohonen
som.grid <- somgrid(xdim = 5, ydim = 5, topo="hexagonal", 
                neighbourhood.fct="gaussian") 
set.seed(1)
som.model <- som(rdf.som, grid=som.grid, rlen=10, alpha=c(0.05,0.01), keep.data = TRUE, dist.fcts = "euclidean", mode = "online")
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a code example that generates the kohoen models you want to save?

Comment: @Emer Yes definitely, please see edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your models can fit into the driver's memory, you can use `spark.lapply`. It is a distributed version of base `lapply` which requires a function and a list. Spark will apply the function to each element of the list (like a map) and collect the returned objects.

Here is an example of fitting kohonen models, one for each iris species:

```
library(SparkR)
library(kohonen)

fit_model <- function(df) {
  library(kohonen)
  grid_size <- ceiling(nrow(df) ^ (1/2.5))
  som_grid <- somgrid(xdim = grid_size, ydim = grid_size, topo = 'hexagonal', toroidal = T)
  som_model <- som(data.matrix(df), grid = som_grid)
  som_model
}

models <- spark.lapply(split(iris[-5], iris$Species), fit_model)
models
```

The `models` variable contains a list of kohonen models fitted in parallel:

```
$setosa
SOM of size 5x5 with a hexagonal toroidal topology.
Training data included.

$versicolor
SOM of size 5x5 with a hexagonal toroidal topology.
Training data included.

$virginica
SOM of size 5x5 with a hexagonal toroidal topology.
Training data included.
```

Then you can save/serialise the R object as usual:

```
saveRDS(models, file="/dbfs/kohonen_models.rds")
```

Note that any file stored into `/dbfs/` path will be available through the Databrick's DBFS, accesible with the CLI or API.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried your proposed solution, but unfortunately Databricks returns me this message after running for 30 minutes: `the spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached.`

Comment: @RinzeBloem try to Detach & re-attach the Notebook. I just tried to code in Databricks Community Edition and works fine. Heres is a link to the notebook: https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1470441163849279/796465212070765/988914346821840/latest.html

Comment: Really sorry to be such a pain @Emer. Managed to solve the previous error, however it is now replaced by `Error in library(kohonen) : there is no package called 'kohonen'` which doesn't make sense as I have installed it multiple times now. I have tried to detach&re-attach but without any luck..

Comment: @RinzeBloem I got the same error the first time I ran the code. Try running `install.packages("kohonen")` in the top cell. Note how it was commented in the shared notebook.

Comment: Unfortunately the same error persists. I literaly copied your workbook and uncommented `install.packages("kohonen")` but with the same result.

Comment: @RinzeBloem try to follow these instructions: https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/workspace-libraries.html#cran-package